# What's this plastic thing along my sidewalk pavers?

Tags: fence, gates

I just moved into a new house and am unable to close my gate because there is something nailed to the ground at the threshold that is sticking up too high for the gate the close. Any idea what this thing is? I'm trying to decide if I just remove it to allow the gate to close or if I need to keep it there and bury it a little deeper.[image: context][image: close up][image: problem]

Comment: Looks vaguely like a plastic drainage ditch but with no top-grate.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That is called **[Paver Edging](https://www.grainger.com/product/E-Z-CONNECT-Patio-Paver-And-Walkway-Edging-13D654)**. It is used to keep the pavers tight or to separate one section from the other. It's usually covered to the point that you only see a small strip of it. However, it looks like the installer didn't quite finish the job. I would probably do as you suggested and bury the edging deeper. You could also take up those few bricks that are outside the gate, level that area a little better and place those bricks closer to the edging for a more uniform look and to stabilize that immediate area.
[image]

Comment: While the ground is soft, you can probably pound it down with a mallet.  You might want to get a few more of those stakes if it doesn't want to stay in place.

Comment: I would suspect that the ground has heaved through a few freeze / thaw cycles.  As mentioned, you can either try to pound it down, or dig it out and secure it again.

Answer (score 4):

Your particular brand, [SnapEdge](http://www.snapedge.ca/snapedge.html) is simply too high.

You can find their [various installation guides PDFs](http://www.snapedge.ca/snap-edge-installation.html) on the web-site.

But the clearest explanation comes from one of their drawings:

[image]

You need to remove the edge, and install it down below the gravel it's next to.

Or you can switch to another product where the edges to "under" the pavers; and are effectively hidden.

Answer (score 3):

Can't upvote or comment at @alephzero's comment... but i'd say he's absolutely right: it was installed upside down. The part that is shown should be down in the dirt to keep a grip and not let the edging move with the seasons (frost heave or heavy rain runoff). The top surface won't be a collection of trip hazards as shown here.

Pull the spikes, turn it over, reinstall, and then finish by covering up the top layer with dirt or mulch or whatever matches.

Comment: not that Youtube is a reliable source, but this video seems to be by the company that makes these things and shows them in the orientation that mine are installed - thoughts? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uYSjHAAP-XQ

Comment: Interestingly this one shows the flat part UNDER the bricks: https://www.olyola.com/install-paver-edging/

Comment: @David Doria, in that first video, I don't think that is the same orientation: Where the spikes are getting driven in looks relatively flat and smooth... I'd assume the fins and built-up spike holes are actually underneath... but as you say, Youtube. :)

The second link shows both orientations. I've never seen the first... but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work... other than needing to have your measurements perfect since you're not pushing it up against already lain bricks... you're leaving a void for the final course. Sounds way harder!

Comment: @DavidDoria What makes YouTube not a "reliable source"? It's simply a platform where anyone can upload videos. It has a *ton* of really high quality and more importantly, accurate content. I don't see why YouTube would be any more or less reliable than getting info from anywhere else. It's just... better because you get a video.

Comment: @only_pro Of course, I love it. But I figured I'd get flack from someone here if my argument was "yea but look how they did it in this youtube video" as if that were an authoritative source.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect some klutz nailed it down back to front, and the raised edge is meant to be on the opposite side, along the edge of the bricks outside your property. If that would make your gate shut properly, just turn it round.

A slightly raised edge may be intentional, since it will stop rainwater runoff flowing downhill and ending up where you don't want it.

Comment: No, it's in the correct orientation. It's there to edge the bricks on the inside of the property, not the outside. The issue is that it's too high near the hinge side of the gate. It appears to have migrated upwards or inward (or just been installed wrong), probably due to being inadequately secured. The latch side of the gate has a clear cut-out so the gate's vertical support (the thicker portion of the gate) will not be obstructed.

Comment: It is not installed properly. It is there to finish the edge of the brick patio on the inside of the property. As is, it is currently sitting too high. Once installed under the bricks the edging will just come up to the brick surface, placing it low enough for the gate to swing over it.

Comment: I think you commented/voted on my answer [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/178845/47125); I have edited to support my position conclusively.

Answer (score 2):

The mentioned [installation instructions](https://www.olyola.com/install-paver-edging/) say:

> [...] our paver edgings may also be installed up against the paver, with the horizontal leg on the outside, if the installation requires it.